# is it good practice to create a variable in a return in javascript?

Tags: javascript, return, return-value

in Javascript, in the return statement of a function, I cannot explicitly declare a variable like that `return let text = "hello world!"`, so far so good

But also, when I declare a variable I can do it without a keyword like `var`, `let` or `const`, it's what w3school call an automatically declared variable : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp like that : `newVariable = "I'm a new variable"` instead of that : `let newVariable = "I'm a new variable"` or that : `const newVariable = "I'm a new const variable"`

Now, I noticed that if I use an automatically declared variable in a return statement, it seems to have declared the variable outside of the function scope :

```js
let myP = document.getElementById("output");

function printInfos(name, age) {
  return info = `${name} is ${age}`;
}

printInfos("john", 4);

myP.textContent = info; // output "john is 4"
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

##### What I suppose is happening is the following :

1. the function return the whole expression after expansion `info = 'john is 4'`
2. then it is evaluated as an automatically declared variable `info`

##### But I wonder how much it is good practice or not ?

I already consider automatically declared variables as bad practice, but in most cases I'm not even sure why other than readability (when I see the variable without keyword I wrongly assume it has been declared earlier), since I can treat them just like a declaration with `let`

But the case of a declaration inside a return statement confuses me since it allows me to do something I cannot do when I "properly" declare the variable, it feels like a bug

so what is it ? Can I use it ?

Comment: If it is pointless, then why do it? There is nothing gained between `return info = \`${name} is ${age}\`;` vs   `return \`${name} is ${age}\``; If you do not declare the var using let, var or const, then it is polluting the global namespace as a var and will have to be Garbage Collected

Comment: Yes it is "normal" that you can do this, but i'd say it's rather a bad practice. 
Likewise if you want to return the variable Info for readabillity, declare it normally and then return info, instead.
You can also declare variables inside of IF-Statements, and in many other places too.

Comment: PS: w3schools is STILL not considered a great resource. Instead use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#declarations)

Comment: @mplungjan I know MDN is a better source than w3schools, but in that case I was just using it for vocabulary : "automatically declared variables". Ok I'll look into the Garbage Collector to see what is happening

Comment: "As variables lose scope, they will be eligible for garbage collection. If they are scoped globally, then they will not be eligible for collection until the global namespace loses scope..."

Comment: @Dxg125 yes I changed my title because "normality" was not my real question, Ok I see, I suppose I should have rather asked why it's possible to create variable without keywords in many places where it's not possible with a keyword like `let`

Comment: That is just one extra proof that you should read some other sources than the infamous "w3schools". Some basics about js variables: `x=12`, if that the first time it is affected is a global variable. `let x=12` is a local variable (bloc-local: `if(true){let x=12;}; console.log(x);` prints `undefined`: `x` is declared only in the `if` {} bloc. So, `return x=12`, sure, it works. It declares a global variable x (but then you don't really need to return it, since `x` is visible by the caller. As you use it).

Comment: `return let x=12`, is a syntax error, but if it weren't, would be pointless: why create a variable that will cease to exist (the variable; not necessary what it points to if your return it) when the function will return, that is right now. Even if `return let x=12` were possible nobody could ever benefit of that `x`.

Comment: My feeling is that you don't really understand `return`. You don't really need to `return info` so that the caller can see it. ``function printInfo(name,age){ info=`${name} is ${age}`;}`` then caller: `printInfo("john",4); myP.textContent=info;` would work. Bad style, imho. But it would work. No need for the return for that. Return would be (and then you don't need a global variable) for ``function printInfo(name, age){ return `${name} is ${age}`;};`` and `myP.textContent=printInfo("john",4);`

Comment: @chrslg allright, the variable cease to exist immediately, I didn't know. And declaration without keyword create a global variable, ok.

Comment: In case your goal are re-usable functions, declaring global variables from within the function or assigning a value onto the next best outer-scope variable forbids itself. Encountering such code mostly comes with a smell. Of cause there are use cases where one has functions which are enclosed by an/other function/s, where such a nested function would alter the value of an outer scope variable. Such functions are mostly not for re-use. They are often either anonymous functions used as callbacks or, if named, serve a special one time purpose.

Comment: "*but in that case I was just using it for vocabulary : "automatically declared variables".*" well, that vocabulary is wrong. There is no "automatic declaration". If you are assigning to an *undeclared* identifier, e.g., `foo = "bar"` then that does not "declare" `foo`. It assigns a value to it. It is called an "implicit global" since assigning to an undeclared identifier does assign to the global object. And all properties of the global object are also global identifiers. But are neither variables, nor declared. It's also an error in strict mode.

Comment: "*But the case of a declaration inside a return statement confuses me since it allows me to do something I cannot do when I "properly" declare the variable*" you can always (attempt to) assign to an identifier. You don't need a `return` statement in there. `info = "hello"` is valid code. However, if such variable has not been declared and you're in strict mode, that would fail. However, it'd fail regardless of the `return` statement: `info = "hello; return info;` and `return info = "hello";` do not exhibit and difference in behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create variables this way only in non-strict mode (which is kind of deprecated).

But it's not creating a new variable but assigning a value to a property of the global object (`window` in our case). So it could be considered that you cannot create a real new variable this way.

That's also bad because you can override any intrinsic or previous values assigned to `window`.
Plus you gain nothing by introducing a new variable in the return statement. Just return.

You assign your function's result to the output element through a intermediate variable. Seems a waste of efforts also. Just assign directly.

You could argue that you cache the result but you can create a memoized function for that (the last snippet)

```js
let myP = document.getElementById("output");

function printInfos(name, age) {
  info = `${name} is ${age}`;
  // it's now a property of window
  console.log(window.info);
  return `${name} is ${age}`;
}

myP.textContent = printInfos("john", 4);
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

In the strict mode you get an error:

```js
'use strict';

let myP = document.getElementById("output");

function printInfos(name, age) {
  info = `${name} is ${age}`;
  console.log(window.info);
  return `${name} is ${age}`;
}

printInfos("john", 4);

myP.textContent = info; // output "john is 4"
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

There are several methods that you could use to avoid declaring a new variable with `const/let/var`, for example through function arguments (the example isn't real life cases):

```js
let myP = document.getElementById("output");

function printInfos(name, age, info = null) {
  info ??= [name, age];
  return info.join(' is ');
}

myP.textContent = printInfos("john", 4);
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

A memoized version (here we use an argument + a closure to avoid variable declaration + hide the argument):

```js
let myP = document.getElementById("output");

const printInfos = (cache => (name, age) => cache[`${name}%${age}`] ??= `${name} is ${age}`)({});

myP.textContent = printInfos("john", 4);
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: And as I commented: "As variables lose scope, they will be eligible for garbage collection. If they are scoped globally, then they will not be eligible for collection until the global namespace loses scope..."

Comment: thx for the explanation, I think you forgot a comment in the strict mode example : it will not output "john is 4", but an error (since it is strict mode)

Comment: @hugogogo i thought it would be obvious that there's an error, will comment

Comment: "*That's also bad because you can override any intrinsic or previous values assigned to window.*" there is another failure mode - that the code *cannot* override certain global properties. Some are immutable and allow assignments (as in, don't throw an error) but do not take on the value. Both are insidious errors that are hard to find because they only show up way later. But overriding a global does carry a higher risk, as it might be in use somewhere else.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev No I meant, in the strict mode example there will be no output but an error, that's your point, I get it. But the code has a comment that says `// output "john is 4"` which is not true, it will not output that. I thought it was an oversight on your part